# List channel subscriptions returns only my channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So, I have a request that should list my subscribers who do not have the private subscriptions option enable. My request is:

```
response = youtube.subscriptions().list(
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=50,
        mySubscribers=True
    ).execute()
```

However, in items resource, every channel returned is my own channel. My channel name, ID and profile images. Is this the problem with the API or am I making a wrong request?
I also tried using the Try this API option on the documentation, but it also returns the same result.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list
Thank you for any help you can give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official docs you already quoted, you should have passed to your API call the parameter `part` as:

`part="snippet,subscriberSnippet"`.

The `subscriberSnippet` part gives you the needed info:

> [**subscriberSnippet**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#subscriberSnippet) (object)
> The `subscriberSnippet` object contains basic details about the subscriber.

For what concerns the `snippet` part, the official doc is indeed a bit ambiguous:

> [**snippet**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#snippet) (object)
> The `snippet` object contains basic details about the subscription, including its title and the channel that the user subscribed to.

Nevertheless, the info you get from `part="snippet"` only is correct.

Comment: So, part snippet only returns my channel because that channel is subscribed to mine. The writing of the documentation was confusing here, but you explained it. Thank you

Comment: The `snippet` part is referring always to your channel, i.e. to the channel to which someone else (not you yourself) made a subscription; indeed the doc of `snippet` is a bit unclear.